# How can I increase the width of the Html.TextBoxFor control beyond its default in an MVC 5 form

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to increase the width of an Html.TextBoxFor control in an ASP.NET MVC 5 View page using razor syntax. I am using Visual Studio 2017. I created a css style (.textboxfor-width) to increase the control's width as shown below but it is not working.

/*  *** Remove this comment line if trying to use in Visual Studio */

```
@using rgmsite.Models
@model LoginTestViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}

<style type="text/css">
    .textboxfor-width {
        width: 700px;
    }
</style>

<h2>SimpleTest</h2>
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account",
              new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post,
              new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email,
                   new {  @class = "form-control textboxfor-width",
                       placeholder = "Enter email address to be used as your user name"
                   })
                </div>
            }
        </section>

 *** Remove this comment line if trying to use in Visual Studio   */
```

Here is the view model (LoginTestViewModel) I am using for the form:

```
/*  *** Remove this comment line if trying to use in Visual Studio   */

  public class LoginTestViewModel
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
  }


 *** Remove this comment line if trying to use in Visual Studio    */
```

Using a smaller width value such as 40px in the css works. But there seems to be some limit imposed on the control preventing it from being wider (such as 700px) than the default.  Flushing the Chrome cache and doing a hard reload is not fixing the problem for me.  What needs to be done to make the TextBoxFor control wider than the default?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That css is not working because you missed  the **.** in css selector. Try this:

```
.textboxfor-width {
    width:600px;
}
```

And it should work.

Comment: This does not work either with or without the period. I am able to make the textbox smaller with a smaller value in the style such as 40px but it won't grow wider than the default.

Comment: This does work now that I am also using the sites.css file I describe in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with MVC 5. However, if MVC 5 sets a default max-width value it could be interfering with your code. You may be able to bypass this by using !important at the end of your width or max-width tag:

```
width: 600px !important;
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: The use of !important is discouraged by most people who write CSS professionally.

Comment: adding !important did not work.  The style can make it smaller but not wider than the default.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple MVC 5 app and added the snipped code and it works fine.
This is the element:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.prop, "", new { @class ="form-control textboxfor-width", placeholder ="Enter email address to be used as your user name"})
```

With styling:

```
.textboxfor-width {
    width: 400px;
}
```

After changing the css I had to empty the cache by doing a hard reload.

Please open google console by right clicking the page and click on inspect.

Once you have opened the console - right click on the reload page and click on 
*Empty cache and hard reload.*

[image]

The . notation is required as you have defined a new class `textboxfor-width`.

Comment: I followed your steps but I do not get a successful run. I made a new simple view page and model but am not able to get it to work. Can you please paste your full View and ViewModel page so I can try it? If it won't paste over correctly then try surrounding it in comments /* */ to insure everything is transferred over.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works for my ASP.NET MVC 5 project but I'm not sure it is needed for other versions of ASP.NET MVC.

The maximum length for the TextBoxFor control is defined in an MVC 5 Project Template file called sites.css which is located in the root of the Content folder of the project.

In there at the bottom is the following:

```
    /*

    /* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */

    input,
    select,
    textarea {
        max-width: 600px;
    } 

 */
```

The reason my defined style in my MVC View file would not work was because the max-width in the sites.css file was originally set to 280px; In the above example, I have already increased the max-width to a value of 600px;  This is strange as I can only set the max width here and not in my own created style tags within my view page. However, I am able to set a lower width with my own defined style in my MVC View. It does not say it includes a TextBoxFor control but it works on it.  I just leave this set to 600px for now. For other cases where I need the TextBoxFor control width to be less I provide my own style width setting on my MVC 5 View page such as the following:

```
/*

<style  type="text/css">
    .textboxfor-width {
        width: 400px;
    }
</style

*/
```

Then I use my defined style (textboxfor-width) with the smaller width in my MVC 5 View as shown below:

```
/*

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {  @class = "form-control textboxfor-width",placeholder = "Enter email address to be used as your user name"})

*/
```

Comment: you got it working :-) . In the end the site.css file was overriding your class textboxfor-width

Answer (score 0):

try with this,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = 
"form-control textboxfor-width", @type = "text",@placeholder = "Enter email 
address to be used as your user name" } })
```